# Twitter bootstrap how to replace dropdown select to menubutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I am resizing the browser screen to mobile size, desktop menu replaced by dropdown with multiple options:

[image]

But how to change that dropdown to menu with button like that:

[image]

By clicking the "Menu" button menu showing and hiding

Answer (score 0):

In order to get menu like above we have to follow this markup

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav">
   <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i> Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Latest Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Popular Products</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>          
   <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Membership<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Personal Membership</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Premium Membership</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Offers</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
</div><!-- /.navbar -->
```

[DEMO](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96099766/Responsive%20Navigation%20Menu/navigation.html)

Comment: Aha, exactly what i need, but i thought this trick is done automatically by jquery...but i cant find a switch from dropdown select to that kind of mobile menu

Comment: yes bootstrap classes and jquery done its automatically :-) if it hepls accept as answer vote it :-)